# Process inbound email in new outlook

Tags: c#, vsto, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've written a VSTO plugin that processes inbound emails and auto-reply when certain criteria are met.

However, I can't get it to work with the new version of outlook. Do I need to do anything special?

From what I can tell, Microsoft recommends web plugins, but they cant process inbound emails, right?

Answer (score 1):

Outlook web add-ins don't provide anything for handling incoming emails like COM add-ins could do. Web add-ins can be activated when an item is selected in the view or opened (they work under the context of selected/opened item only). With MS Graph API you can set up a notification for items in Outlook, see [Microsoft Graph API change notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/change-notifications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) for more information.

You may find the [Build JavaScript apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript?tabs=aad) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. VSTO add-ins are not supported in the latest version of Outlook, and the JS API does cannot directly detect incoming mails.

However, you can poll the server to detect incoming mails using a system such as fetchmail. If you need something in the Outlook UI to happen, you could use SignalR to send a notification to an Outlook add-in there. The only thing is that you might need the taskpane for the add-in to be open for this to work.

Office add-ins are just web pages that open in a taskpane like it's a browser with some ability to interact with the office application.

https://www.fetchmail.info/

Comment: That is not true. Web add-ins are not only task panes.